# Get data from MongoDB in a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a question.

Context:
Each hour the bot sends an image of a random famous person
The users of the server can claim the famous person by claiming it

I have a Mongo.db database with 3 fields:
playerDBName: the name of a famous person
times: the number of times that someone has that person
userNameClaim: the id of the user that claimed that person, that many times

---

My problem:
I have a "/collection" command, but it doesn't work.

I want that:
1º) if someone uses "/collection", the bot checks the fields in which the "userNameClaim" === "interaction.user.id"
2º) the bot gets the "playerDBName" values if the action above is fulfilled
3º) the bot writes an embed ->
Title: ${interaction.user.username}'s collection
Description: Here is your collection
4º) Create a field in that embed per player (featuring the number of times that the user has each player ("times"))

I have tried using this code:

````js
if (interaction.isCommand()) {
  if (interaction.commandName === 'collection') {
    const playersCollection = await playersSchema.find({ userNameClaim: interaction.user.id });

        const embedCollection = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`${interaction.user.username}'s Collection`)
        .setDescription('Here are the players you have claimed:');

        playersCollection.forEach(playersSchema => {
            embedCollection.addField(playersSchema.players.playerDBName, `Claimed ${player.times} time(s)`);
        });

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [embedCollection] });
}}```

But when I use the command the bot sends the embed with the title and the description but not the fields
````

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method as well as wrong data type. From the [docs](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/builders/1.5.0/EmbedBuilder:Class#addFields), you can see the correct method is `addFields()`.

> This method accepts either an array of fields or a variable number of
> field parameters. The maximum amount of fields that can be added is
> 25.

Hence you need to do this:

```
if (interaction.isCommand()) {
  if (interaction.commandName === "collection") {
    const playersCollection = await playersSchema.find({
      userNameClaim: interaction.user.id,
    });

    const fields = [];

    playersCollection.forEach((playersSchema) => {
      fields.push({
        name: playersSchema.players.playerDBName,
        value: `Claimed ${player.times} time(s)`,
      });
    });

    const embedCollection = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(`${interaction.user.username}'s Collection`)
      .setDescription("Here are the players you have claimed:")
      .addFields(fields);

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embedCollection] });
  }
}
```

**References:**

1. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor
2. https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/builders/1.5.0/EmbedBuilder:Class#addFields